# Changing orientation of widget breaks it

Tags: android, android-widget

So I made a pretty basic widget that has a list view and a manual update button. However, on tablets when I change the orientation of the device, the listview disappears and the button become unclickable. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Do your landscape and portrait views use the same layout file?  Was there any error in logcat?

Comment: Yes both use the same layout file, No error in logcat

Comment: Then perhaps the listview is still there, but just not visible.  It could be blocked, or maybe the width setting has result in it having a width of zero.

Comment: Does changing the orientation call any methods? Also now when i resize the widget, the listview starts to load its images